# Why do I get this error "java.io.IOException: Error: Header doesn't contain versioninfo" when using PDFBox?

Tags: java, pdfbox

This is my first time posting here so sorry if I didn't do it correctly. I am trying to write a program that finds certain patterns in a folder of pdfs and then prints them as a list using PDFBox. Currently, it will find pattern matches in some of the files, but not all of them, even though I checked and there should be one in each file. It also returns an error before printing that says "java.io.IOException: Error: Header doesn't contain versioninfo". I am wondering if this is the reason that it doesn't return some of the pattern matches? And if it is, how do I fix it? The whole try/catch/finally part was kind of confusing to me, so perhaps it has to do with that. (I removed some code that isn't necessary for the question)

```
public class PDF
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException

    {
        String number;
        String name;
        String state;
        String numberR =  "\\d{3}([.-])?\\d{3}\\1?\\d{4}|\\(\\d{3}\\)([.-])?\\d{3}\\2?\\d{4}|\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s\\d{3}([.-])?\\d{4}";
        String stateR = "[,]\\sAL\\s|[,]\\sMT\\s|[,]\\sAK\\s|[,]\\sNE\\s|[,]\\sAZ\\s|[,]\\sNV\\s|[,]\\sAR\\s|[,]\\sNH\\s|[,]\\sCA\\s|[,]\\sNJ\\s|[,]\\sCO\\s|[,]\\sNM\\s|[,]\\sCT\\s|[,]\\sNY\\s|[,]\\sDE\\s|[,]\\sNC\\s|[,]\\sFL\\s|[,]\\sND\\s|[,]\\sGA\\s|[,]\\sOH\\s|[,]\\sHI\\s|[,]\\sOK\\s|[,]\\sID\\s|[,]\\sOR\\s|[,]\\sIL\\s|[,]\\sPA\\s|[,]\\sIN\\s|[,]\\sRI\\s|[,]\\sIA\\s|[,]\\sSC\\s|[,]\\sKS\\s|[,]\\sSD\\s|[,]\\sKY\\s|[,]\\sTN\\s|[,]\\sLA\\s|[,]\\sTX\\s|[,]\\sME\\s|[,]\\sUT\\s|[,]\\sMD\\s|[,]\\sVT\\s|[,]\\sMA\\s|[,]\\sVA\\s|[,]\\sMI\\s|[,]\\sWA\\s|[,]\\sMN\\s|[,]\\sWV\\s|[,]\\sMS\\s|[,]\\sWI\\s|[,]\\sMO\\s|[,]\\sWY\\s|s";
        File folder = new File("/Users/bob/Desktop/");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();
        for (File file : listOfFiles) 
        {
            if (file.isFile())
            {
                name = file.getName();
                state = findInfo(stateR, name);
                number = findInfo(numberR, name);
                System.out.print(name + "       " + number + "     " + state.substring(1));
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }

    public static String findInfo(String regex,String name) throws IOException
    {
        File input = new File("/Users/bob/Desktop/" + name);
        PDDocument pd = null;
        try 
        {
            pd = PDDocument.load(input);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            PDFTextStripper stripper = new PDFTextStripper();
            stripper.setStartPage(1);
            sb.append(stripper.getText(pd));
            Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regex);
            Matcher m = p.matcher(sb);

            while (m.find())
            {
                return m.group();
            }

        } 
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return " ";
        }
        finally
        {   
            if (pd != null)
            {
                pd.close();
            }
        }
        return " ";
     }      
}
```

Edit: Perhaps it has to do with how PDFBox is reading the files? I tried printing out one of the files that didn't work and got this:

"

```
         !"#    $%&'(! (
```

)            *$

```
    +   )
,-
```

."/!01%%23/4$56667
"
        $$4$% 8 %85 % $8    -   %
,(# 58"89$"
...

Comment: I guess you should use the pdfbox version 1.4 or above.

Comment: I am using the newest version that is on their website. I believe it is 1.8.10

Comment: I tested your code with a set of 12 pdf files and works as expected. Identify the pdf file with problems, upload it and maybe I we can help you more

Comment: Did you not get the header error? Can you send me which pdfs you used? Unfortunately I cannot send you the pdfs I am working with because they are confidential, but I can try to find similar ones that also don't work.

Comment: Yes, please try to find non-confidential files to reproduce your issue with. Pdfbox usually has no problems reading valid pdfs...

Comment: Maybe one of these files isn't a PDF at all?

Comment: They are all .pdf but perhaps the error is because of different encoding? I'm still looking for an online file that doesn't work; so far all the ones I have found have worked.

Comment: check that the file starts with %PDF1.

Comment: Are you possibly using an IBM mainframe OS ?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and its because you are reading a incorrect `pdf` file here

```
PDDocument.load(input);
```

when you try to load a different `pdf` file, `PDFBox` will thrown that error

Answer (score 0):

You are reading **ALL** kinds of files located within the (**Desktop**) directory.
If there happens to be a non PDF file within that directory,
This Error will occur upon trying to read the next File.
Even if this (Next) File is a valid PDF.

**Possible Solutions:**

- Remove Files that are NOT of PDF format from that directory.
  OR
- Filter Out non PDF files (e.g using Regex) before calling `PDDocument.load(input);`
  # where `input` is the name of a valid PDF file at any given time.

Answer (score -4):

I got the same problem. I resolved it by using maven dependencies for PDFBox with LOG4J & SLF4J loggings. Must configure log4j.properties to the src in the project. Firstly make sure all the documents contains .pdf extension.

Comment: Log4J Logging & PDFBox both are completely different. Answer is not related to this question.